# How to hide a div in Knockout.js until JSON is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js and trying to hide and show sections of a page while JSON is loading. The loader.gif should show while there is no data, and the template should show after the data exists. Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="loader" data-bind="visible: $data === undefined">
        <img src="/static/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading">
    </div>
    <div id="mainArea" data-bind="visible: $data !== undefined">
        [The main template is here.
            It should only show after the JSON has loaded]
    </div>
    ...
```

The loader.gif section shows and hides as expected, but the template doesn't hide during loading. I added `display: none` to the CSS file so that it doesn't show until the bindings are applied and the data has loaded, but when I do that, the `#mainArea` never shows at all.

I've also tried using `data-bind="visible: myObservableArray().length > 0"`, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

Comment: My data loads. It just doesn't hide. I did try that `visible: tasks().length > 0` technique, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put an observable property in your viewmodel like `dataLoaded`. Initialize it as `false` in your viewmodel. Then in the AJAX callback, set it to `true`. Use it in your `visible`-binding:

```
<div class="loader" data-bind="visible: !dataLoaded">
    <img src="/static/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading">
</div>
<div id="mainArea" data-bind="visible: dataLoaded">
    <!--The main template is here.
        It should only show after the JSON has loaded-->
</div>
```

Remember to set it back to `false` at the start of your AJAX calls again.

Simple example:

```
var self = this;
/* ... */
self.dataLoaded = ko.observable(false);
/* ... */
function successCallback(result) {
    /* do whatever you need with your AJAX result */
    self.dataLoaded(true);
}
/* ... */
self.getTheData = function(optionalParams) {
    /* ... */
    self.dataLoaded(false);
    $.getJSON(someUrl, successCallback);
}
```

Working example using a setTimeout to fake the asynchronicity of an ajax call:

http://jsbin.com/zizidofidu/edit?html,js,output

Please note that the visible binding only removes inline-styled `display: none;` when the binding condition resolves to `true`, so you cannot put that in your non-inline CSS, otherwise the binding cannot make it visible.

Comment: Thanks. I would expect that to work, but it doesn't override the `display: none` in the CSS. I've done `console.log(self.dataLoaded());` in the success callback and it's `true`, but still the div is hidden. I've tried both `<div id="mainArea" data-bind="visible: dataLoaded">` and `<div id="mainArea" data-bind="visible: dataLoaded()">`.

Comment: There should be no `display: none;` in the css since you allow Knockout to control the visibility. Anyway I'd expect Knockout implements the hiding and showing by applying inline-styles which in any case should be more specific than even id-based styles (except if they have `!important` flag in your css).

Comment: Knockout hasn't applied bindings yet when the page is loading, so it remains visible for a moment if I don't hide it by default. I'm not sure how to get around that without setting `display: none` in a CSS file.

Comment: From the KO docs for visible binding: "When the parameter resolves to a true-like value (e.g., the boolean value true, or a non-null object or array), the binding removes the yourElement.style.display value, causing it to become visible. Note that any display style you’ve configured using CSS will then apply (so CSS rules like display:table-row work fine in conjunction with this binding)." http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused. The jsbin doesn't seem to work either. Tested in Firefox and Chromium. `<h1>Main Area</h1>` never shows.

Comment: It does work if you apply your initial display: none as an inline style, because that is what KO removes later actually. Updated the bin accordingly & learnt something new myself!

Comment: Thanks, that works! If you update the original answer with the inline `display:none` and `visible: dataLoaded()`, I can mark it as the correct one.